# User Defined Table Types entre bases de dados diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Criei um `User Defined Table Type` numa base de dados DB1. Se tentar declarar uma variável desse tipo num procedimento de uma base de dados BD2 dá-me o seguinte erro:

> The type name 'BLABLA' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes.

Como não consegui resolver deste modo, tentei criar o mesmo tipo de dados em ambas as bases de dados. A declaração nao deu erro, mas ao tentar enviar o tipo de dados criados na base de dados DB2 para um procedimento na DB1 dá o seguinte erro:

> "Operant type clash"

Existe alguma forma de conseguir enviar uma tabela de dados de um procedimento de uma base de dados DB2 para um procedimento de uma base de dados DB1?

Comment: Já tentou replicar a UDT no DB2 ?

Comment: sim, já fiz isso e dá-me este erro tbm "Operant type clash".

Comment: De acordo com essa pergunta do SO isso não é possível: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531769/passing-table-valued-parameter-to-stored-procedure-across-different-databases/9532187#9532187

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem

> Operand Type Clash

quer dizer que você declarou os dois tipos em bancos de dados diferentes e eles possuem alguma diferença entre eles que faz o banco de dados se perder.

[Há um artigo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178069(v=sql.105).aspx) em que a Microsoft esclarece como isso funciona, bem como recomenda uma série de precauções ao lidar com User Defined Types.